# PHPExcel not working with xls file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com)   to read excel file in php,it is working fine with `xlsx` but when try to read `xls` file,It shows an error

```
     Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Reader_CSV::setReadDataOnly() in /var/www/....
```

Here is my code

```
            $file_path='/var/www/html/site/sample.xls';
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $file_path);

            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);  

            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

            /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/  
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $file_path);

            $total_sheets=$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(); 

            $allSheetName=$objPHPExcel->getSheetNames(); 
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
            $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); 
            $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();  
            $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);  
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow;++$row) 
            {  
                for ($col = 0; $col <$highestColumnIndex;++$col)
                {  
                    $value=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();  

                          $arraydata[$row-1][$col]=trim($value); 


                }  

            }
```

Comment: Maybe `$file_path` is wrong? Try add `if (!!file_exists($file_path)) return;` to the begin

Comment: @hindmost $file_path is not wrong,I double checked

Answer (score 2):

The file that you're loading is identified as a `CSV` file, even though it has an `.xls` extension... it is quite a common practise for some developers to save files formatted as csv or with html markup with a .xls extension, but that doesn't make them BIFF-format .xls files.

The `setReadDataOnly()` method isn't available for the CSV Reader, because a CSV file cannot contain anything other than data.

The most recent versions of PHPExcel provide a stub for `setReadDataOnly()` in the CSV Reader to prevent an error in this situation, and I'd certainly recommend that you upgrade to the latest code; but if you can't do that, then the simplest fix for you is simply to wrap the call to `setReadDataOnly()` in an `if` test:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $file_path);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);  
if ($inputFileType !== 'CSV') {
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
}
```

Comment: If you get a fatal error when you call `setReadDataOnly()` before calling `load`, then the data __won't__ be read.... `load()` is the method that actually reads the data into a PHPExcel object that you then assign to `$objPHPExcel`.... but a fatal error before that terminates the script

Answer (score 0):

For binary Excel files (xls) you may have better luck using the (old) [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/). It's the most reliable one I've found so far.

Comment: I need both xls and xlsx,i upgraded it for xlsx